# Converter query SQL para MongoDB

Tags: sql, query, mongodb, nosql

Tenho pouco (ou nenhum) conhecimento em bancos não-relacionais. Preciso converter a consulta abaixo (SQLite) em uma query equivalente a ser executada no MongoDB.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match_table
WHERE (home_team_api_id=9991 AND home_team_goal > away_team_goal)     
OR (away_team_api_id=9991 AND away_team_goal > home_team_goal);
```

Pelo que entendi, o MongoDB não aceita querys com agrupamento em parênteses, entre outras "incompatibilidades". É possível realizar uma query equivalente no MongoDB?? Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ficaria assim:

```
db.match_table.find({
   "$or":[
      {
         "$and":[
            {
               home_team_api_id:9991
            },
            {
               "home_team_goal":{
                  "$gt":"away_team_goal"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "$and":[
            {
               "away_team_api_id":9991
            },
            {
               "away_team_goal":{
                  "$gt":"home_team_goal"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}).count()
```

Pode usar esse link para ajudar: https://klaus.dk/sqltomongodb/

Comment: Assim a consulta MongoDB está comparando o membro `away_team_goal` com a string `"home_team_goal"`, e vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

```
db.match_table.find({$or: [ [ {"home_team_api_id": 9991}, {$where: "this.home_team_goal > this.away_team_goal"} ], [ {"away_team_api_id": 9991}, {$where: "this.away_team_goal > this.home_team_goal"} ] ]}).count()
```